# Get geojson elements into a html table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, geojson

I'm a JS-starter and have the question how to insert geojson-entries like "ename" etc. into a html-table:

```
<table id="jsoncontent"></table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var golfdata = $.getJSON('golf.js');
        document.getElementById("jsoncontent").innerHtml = '<p>'
            golfdata.properties.[ename] + '</p>';
    };
</script>
<script src='data/data.js'></script>
```

The geojson (data.js) has this content:

```
var golf = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { 
        "name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } 
    },                                                                        
    "features": [
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ename": "PGA Championship", "efdate": "10.08.2015", "etdate": "16.08.2016", "esportcat": "Golf", "elocnam": "Whistling Straits", "elocstree": "N8501 County Road LS", "ecity": "Sheboygan", "eloczip": "WI 53083", "elocland": "USA", "eclubnam": null, "elink": "http:\/\/www.pga.com\/pgachampionship\/", "addrtype": "street_address", "addrlocat": "ROOFTOP" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -87.7351084, 43.8509493 ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ename": "Ryder Cup 2016", "efdate": "01.09.2016", "etdate": "02.10.2016", "esportcat": "Golf", "elocnam": "Hazeltine National Golf Course", "elocstree": "1900 Hazeltine Blvd", "ecity": "Chaska", "eloczip": "MN 55318", "elocland": "USA", "eclubnam": null, "elink": "http:\/\/www.rydercup.com\/", "addrtype": "street_address", "addrlocat": "ROOFTOP" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -93.5908194, 44.833729 ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ename": "2015 Toshiba Classic", "efdate": "26.10.2015", "etdate": "01.11.2015", "esportcat": "Golf", "elocnam": "Newport Beach Country Club", "elocstree": "1600 East Coast Hwy", "ecity": "Newport Beach", "eloczip": "CA 92660", "elocland": "California, USA", "eclubnam": "Newport Beach Country Club", "elink": "http:\/\/www.toshibaclassic.com\/", "addrtype": "street_address", "addrlocat": "ROOFTOP" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -117.8829118, 33.615317 ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ename": "HSBC Champions", "efdate": "04.11.2015", "etdate": "08.11.2015", "esportcat": "Golf", "elocnam": "Sheshan International Golf Club", "elocstree": "288 Linyin New Rd", "ecity": "Shanghai", "eloczip": null, "elocland": "China", "eclubnam": "Sheshan International Golf Club", "elink": "http:\/\/www.worldgolfchampionships.com\/hsbc-champions.html", "addrtype": "street_address", "addrlocat": "ROOFTOP" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 121.22203, 31.104027 ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ename": "Cadillac Championship", "efdate": "02.03.2016", "etdate": "06.03.2016", "esportcat": "Golf", "elocnam": "Trump National Doral Miami", "elocstree": "4400 N.W. 87th Avenue", "ecity": "Miami", "eloczip": "FL 33178", "elocland": "USA", "eclubnam": "Trump National Doral Golf Club", "elink": "http:\/\/www.worldgolfchampionships.com\/cadillac-championship.html", "addrtype": "street_address", "addrlocat": "ROOFTOP" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -80.3395621, 25.814003 ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ename": "Dell Match Play", "efdate": "23.03.2016", "etdate": "27.03.2016", "esportcat": "Golf", "elocnam": "Austin Country Club", "elocstree": "4408 Long Champ Dr", "ecity": "Austin", "eloczip": "TX 78746", "elocland": "USA", "eclubnam": "Austin Country Club", "elink": "http:\/\/www.worldgolfchampionships.com\/dell-match-play.html", "addrtype": "street_address", "addrlocat": "ROOFTOP" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -97.7975758, 30.3425085 ] } }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need may be:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var golfdata = $.getJSON("golf.js");
  golfdata.features.forEach(function(entry) {
    document.getElementById("jsoncontent").innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + entry.ename + "</td></tr>";
  });
};
```

I'll provide a more complete solution, wait a minute.

```js
var golfdata = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },

    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "ename": "PGA Championship",
                "efdate": "10.08.2015",
                "etdate": "16.08.2016",
                "esportcat": "Golf",
                "elocnam": "Whistling Straits",
                "elocstree": "N8501 County Road LS",
                "ecity": "Sheboygan",
                "eloczip": "WI 53083",
                "elocland": "USA",
                "eclubnam": null,
                "elink": "http:\/\/www.pga.com\/pgachampionship\/",
                "addrtype": "street_address",
                "addrlocat": "ROOFTOP"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-87.7351084, 43.8509493]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "ename": "Ryder Cup 2016",
                "efdate": "01.09.2016",
                "etdate": "02.10.2016",
                "esportcat": "Golf",
                "elocnam": "Hazeltine National Golf Course",
                "elocstree": "1900 Hazeltine Blvd",
                "ecity": "Chaska",
                "eloczip": "MN 55318",
                "elocland": "USA",
                "eclubnam": null,
                "elink": "http:\/\/www.rydercup.com\/",
                "addrtype": "street_address",
                "addrlocat": "ROOFTOP"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-93.5908194, 44.833729]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "ename": "2015 Toshiba Classic",
                "efdate": "26.10.2015",
                "etdate": "01.11.2015",
                "esportcat": "Golf",
                "elocnam": "Newport Beach Country Club",
                "elocstree": "1600 East Coast Hwy",
                "ecity": "Newport Beach",
                "eloczip": "CA 92660",
                "elocland": "California, USA",
                "eclubnam": "Newport Beach Country Club",
                "elink": "http:\/\/www.toshibaclassic.com\/",
                "addrtype": "street_address",
                "addrlocat": "ROOFTOP"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-117.8829118, 33.615317]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "ename": "HSBC Champions",
                "efdate": "04.11.2015",
                "etdate": "08.11.2015",
                "esportcat": "Golf",
                "elocnam": "Sheshan International Golf Club",
                "elocstree": "288 Linyin New Rd",
                "ecity": "Shanghai",
                "eloczip": null,
                "elocland": "China",
                "eclubnam": "Sheshan International Golf Club",
                "elink": "http:\/\/www.worldgolfchampionships.com\/hsbc-champions.html",
                "addrtype": "street_address",
                "addrlocat": "ROOFTOP"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [121.22203, 31.104027]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "ename": "Cadillac Championship",
                "efdate": "02.03.2016",
                "etdate": "06.03.2016",
                "esportcat": "Golf",
                "elocnam": "Trump National Doral Miami",
                "elocstree": "4400 N.W. 87th Avenue",
                "ecity": "Miami",
                "eloczip": "FL 33178",
                "elocland": "USA",
                "eclubnam": "Trump National Doral Golf Club",
                "elink": "http:\/\/www.worldgolfchampionships.com\/cadillac-championship.html",
                "addrtype": "street_address",
                "addrlocat": "ROOFTOP"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-80.3395621, 25.814003]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "ename": "Dell Match Play",
                "efdate": "23.03.2016",
                "etdate": "27.03.2016",
                "esportcat": "Golf",
                "elocnam": "Austin Country Club",
                "elocstree": "4408 Long Champ Dr",
                "ecity": "Austin",
                "eloczip": "TX 78746",
                "elocland": "USA",
                "eclubnam": "Austin Country Club",
                "elink": "http:\/\/www.worldgolfchampionships.com\/dell-match-play.html",
                "addrtype": "street_address",
                "addrlocat": "ROOFTOP"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-97.7975758, 30.3425085]
            }
        }
    ]
};

window.onload = function() {
    // var golfdata = $.getJSON("golf.js");
    document.getElementById("jsoncontent").innerHTML = "<tr><th>ename</th><th>elocnam</th>";
  
    golfdata.features.forEach(function(entry) {
        document.getElementById("jsoncontent").innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + entry.properties.ename + "</td><td>" + entry.properties.elocnam + "</td></tr>";
    });
};
```

```html
<table id="jsoncontent"></table>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try.

Comment: Great solution. Unfortunately I'm not able to upvote without reputation.